# Put a new line in the title in server.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following in my server.R. My goal is to put a new line between Grades and (from 2010 to 2012) and center the title.

```
output$title <- renderText({
paste("Analysis for Grades <br>(from 2010 to 2012)")}
```

This obviously doesn't work as it is simply considers the br as a string and concatenates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `reunderUI()`:

```
output$title <- renderUI(list(
        p("Analysis for Grades"),
        br(),
        p("(from 2010 to 2012)")))
```

or maybe

```
output$title <- renderUI(list(
        "Analysis for Grades",
        br(),
        "(from 2010 to 2012)"))
```